# Confusion regarding the method to solve combinations with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Looking at some examples and the methods involved in solving combinations with repetition, for example with the problem, how many distinct solutions are there to:

```
a + b = 10, where a>=0
```

Intuitively, well there are 6 solutions:

```
0 + 10 
1 + 9
2 + 8
3 + 7
4 + 6
5 + 5
```

I have left out 6 + 4 etc.. As order does not matter so these arrangements will not count.
Now using the formula of combinations with repetition:

```
(n + r − 1)! / r!(n − 1)!  =>  11! / 10! = 11
```

I get 11 combinations, so the formula is including what I had left out ie (6 + 4) .... (10 + 0). But wouldn't this now mean that order does matter?

Comment: The solution $a =6, b=4$ is not the same as  $a=4,b=6$.  (You probably also need $b \ge0$ in your original equation)

Comment: Yh I forgot to add that, but with combinations order does not matter so aren't those the same?

Comment: I would say your approach is related to partitions of $10$ into two non-negative integer parts, while the question is asking for compositions of $10$ into two non-negative integers.  With compositions, order matters, even when like combinations the approach involves binomial coefficients

Comment: You have to explain why you think 11 choose 10 is the answer. I suspect you do not understand what combinations are.

Comment: I understand how they get 11!/10!, you have 11 objects which can be arranged in 11! ways and because of the duplicates ie 10 duplicate objects, you divide by 10! to filter those out. But this gets a permutation as opposed to a combination where order does not matter, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember why the $a+b=10$ problem is relevant to counting "combinations with repetition." Let's look at a bigger example, say, counting integer solutions $a+b+c+d=8,$ with $a,b,c,d\ge 0.$ The reason we care about solutions to this equation is that they represent ways to select $8$ items from a pool of $4$ items, where repetition is allowed and **order of the selected item does not matter.** The variable $a$ represents the number of times the first item is selected, $b$ corresponds to the second item, etc. Therefore, whether order matters or not depends on which lens you are looking at the problem with.

- If you are thinking of the solution in terms of quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $a+b+c+d=8$, then order **does** matter. $(3,2,2,1)$ is different from $(2,3,2,1)$.
- If you are thinking of the solution in terms of combinations with repetition, then order **does not matter**. If the set being chosen from is $\{A,B,C,D\}$, the $(3,2,2,1)$ corresponds to $\{A,A,A,B,B,C,C,D\}$, which would be the same as $\{A,B,C,A,B,C,D,A\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I get it now.

Comment: I'm assuming there should be a D in the last set?

Comment: Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $b$ is fully determined by $a,$ so each distinct solution $(a_k,b_k)$ is just $(a_k,10-a_k).$

In other words, notice that the question can be equivalently rephrased as "How many distinct non-negative integer values of $a$ satisfy $a+b=10$?"

Thus, there are indeed 11 distinct solutions, where $k\in\{0,2,\ldots,10\}$ and $a_k=k.$